# Web Developer Designation hierarchy to implement in the Web Development Department

Tags: hierarchy

I have been in search for a Web Developer Designation hierarchy to implement in the Web Development Department in the company that I work.

for eg: Associate Web Developer -> Web Developer -> Senior Web Developer -> what next?

Please Suggest..!!

Comment: I have similar question. currently i am working one company they are confuse a bit for my designation. also i am very much experience more than 12+ years. what i am doing there

web design, mobile app ui, graphic design, poster flyer etc... web and app development (html+css+js+wordpress). and supporting (give them concept and solve them problem mostly html css js issue) other web and graphic team.

Comment: @pagol how about "Web Master" or "Web Consultant" looks like you are more into the design segment than programming, in that case how about "UI Specialist"

Comment: Web Consultant not bad at all to listen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about 'Web Architect'?

Around here, the next step up from 'Senior Developer' is usually 'Architect', if that is what the individual is interested in.